# Is there a way to parse each row of a matrix in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am new to Octave and I wanted to know if there is a way to parse each row of a matrix and use it individually. Ultimately I want to use the rows to check if they are all vertical to each other (the dot product have to be equal to 0 for two vectors to be vertical to each other) so if you have some ideas about that I would love to hear them. Also I wanted to know if there is a function to determine the length (or the amplitude) of a vector.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "parse each row" you mean a loop that takes each row one by one, you only need a [`for`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop over the [transposed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) matrix. This works because the `for` loop takes successive *columns* of its argument.

Example:

```
A = [10 20; 30 40; 50 60];
for row = A.'; % loop over columns of transposed matrix 
   row = row.'; % transpose back to obtain rows of the original matrix
   disp(row); % do whatever you need with each row
end
```

However, loops can often be avoided in Matlab/Octave, in favour of [vectorized](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) code. For the specific case you mention, computing the dot product between each pair of rows of `A` is the same as computing the [matrix product](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) of `A` times itself transposed:

```
A*A.'
```

However, for the general case of a complex matrix, the dot product is defined with a complex conjugate, so you should use the [complex-conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html):

```
P = A*A';
```

Now `P(m,n)` contains the dot product of the `n`-th and `m`-th rows of `A`. The condition you want to test is equivalent to `P` being a [diagonal matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isdiag.html):

```
result = isdiag(P); % gives true of false
```